# Kotlin generate generic java code

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I have an interface in kotlin, which looks something like this

```
interface BaseDao<in M : Model> {

    ...

    @Delete
    fun delete(models: Collection<M>)

    ...

}
```

Now when I look at the generated code I see something like this:

```
public interface BaseDao {

    ...

    @Delete
    void delete(@NotNull Collection var1);

    ...

}
```

Is there a way to tell kotlin that I want the type of the collection explicitly set?

Comment: Type arguments are for syntax checking at compile time. Generated code always uses `Object`s. (Sometimes adds casting.)

Answer (score 4):

The 'generated code' is actually compiled byte-code decompiled to Java. And since generic types are lost due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you will see plain `Collection`.

When working with the code from Java, the function still enforces the correct types.